# application executable is missing a required architecture

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution

I'm attempting to upload my first app to the app store using xcode 4.3, but can't get past this error... "application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architectures must be present: armv7" I looked up the issue. Their are several post on stackoverflow addressing the issue, but none of the suggestions listed worked. I attempted to add armv6 and armv7 to the build settings, but the errors still persist. Any suggestions would be welcomed. Thanks.

screen shot here..
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2813968/Build%20Settings.png

Comment: That definitely should fix it. Can you post a screen shot of your build settings?

Comment: are you sure you're not overriding the architecture from project setting in the target setting?

Comment: Here are my project setting..
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2813968/projectInfo.png
Am I doing anything wrong there?
This is so frustrating. The app works great on my test devices.

Comment: Thats not what I wanted to see - I wanted to see your Build Settings: http://3dtopo.com/BuildSettings.png

Comment: Here they are... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2813968/build2.png

Comment: Should I just rebuild the project from scratch? Kind of pain, but I don't know what else to do. Frustrating. Who would have thought that creating the app would be the easy part.

Answer (score 3):

For Xcode 4.5 at least, set the deployment target to at least iOS 4.3 and that will resolve it. Earlier versions of iOS and armv6 are almost extinct.

Comment: This worked for me after an hour of head scratching. Couldn't understand why it kept asking for armv6 when my Architectures were all set to armv7 and up.

Comment: My app was set to iOS 4.0 prior to XCode 4.5, and setting the deployment target to 4.3 solved this issue for me. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that these settings match your **Target** and not just your **Project** settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Left-click project icon (blue icon, under "Run" button).

2) Next to the project icon (to the right of it), left-click on project name under "PROJECT" (White background).

3)Select tab "Build Settings" and look for  tab "Build Active Architecture Only" -----change to -----no